# Clickable mailto link in custom order grid?

Tags: magento-1.7, order-grid

**Magento 1.7.0.2**

This is how I show the mail address from my collection in my custom order grid:

```
$this->addColumn('mail', array(
        'header'       => $helper->__('E-Mail'),
        'index'        => 'mail',
        'filter_index' => 'mail',
    ));
```

This works, but I want that shown value (which is a mail address) to be a mailto link. How would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using a renderer

https://stackoverflow.com/q/12931626/10121426

Although take note of the minor edit in the answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12931725/10121426